# How to access a row in a data frame by using first column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
    intercatedData                 n

1 Completed Degree in 2 Years.0    2
2  Retained to Midyear Year 2.0    1
3 Retained to Start of Year 2.0    1
4  Retained to Midyear Year 2.1    1
5 Retained to Start of Year 2.1    1
```

Here is the data `frame(mydf)` that i am using.

Now i want access first row value (that is `2`) by its name (`Completed Degree in 2 Years.0`). I am able to access the value by using `print(mydf$n[1])` but  right I would like to access the value by name instead of by index `1`.

How can I access the value by name instead of by index ?

Comment: Have you tried `xy[xy$intercatedData %in% c("Completed Degree in 2 Years.0"), ]`? By using `%in%`, you can add extra arguments and extract multiple rows.

Comment: Alternatively, `subset(mydf, intercatedData == "Completed Degree in 2 Years.0")` will give you a data frame with all lines which satisfy the test.

Answer (score 1):

```
mydf[ mydf$intercatedData == 'Completed Degree in 2 Years.0', ]
```

A DATA record in a dataframe has a row AND column and so can be referred as so

`mydf[2,3]` will give me record in 2nd row and 3rd column for dataframe named mydf

`mydf[2,]` will give me record in 2nd row and all columns for that for dataframe named mydf

`mydf[,3]` will give me records in 3rd column for dataframe named mydf

This dataframe property can now be used for conditional selection

```
mydf[ mydf$intercatedData == 'Completed Degree in 2 Years.0', ]
```

Says give me all rows where the value for mydf$intercatedData is 'Completed Degree in 2 Years.0' and all columns

Comment: Thanks ajay and conradkdotcom . I appreciate your help

Comment: elaborated the dataframe way of accessing data